# IntelliJ runs Kotlin tests annotated with @Ignore

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, junit5

I have a Kotlin project that uses JUnit 5.2.0. When I use IntelliJ to run tests, it runs all tests, even those annotated with `@org.junit.Ignore`.

```
package my.package

import org.junit.Ignore
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class ExampleTests {

    @Test fun runMe() {
        assertEquals(1, 1)
    }

    @Test @Ignore fun dontRunMe() {
        assertEquals(1, 0)
    }
}
```

[image: IntelliJ Test Runner]

Can anyone explain to me why this might be happening?

Answer (score 19):

In JUnit 5 you need to use [@Disabled](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Disabled.html) annotation for that purpose.

Answer (score 13):

Figured out the answer: JUnit5 replaces JUnit4's `@Ignore` with `@Disabled`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class ExampleTests {

    @Test fun runMe() {
        assertEquals(1, 1)
    }

    @Test @Disabled fun dontRunMe() {
        assertEquals(1, 0)
    }
}
```

[image: IDEA test runner]